# Ansible, override single module file

Tags: ansible

I want to tweak one Ansible module, I am using multiple modules. Now I want minor tweaks in one of them. How can I override default code?

I am not sure but my assumption is if I created a similar directory structure of modules in current directory, it will refer this code and for rest of module it will refer default code eg. for `yum_repository module`, default path is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.4.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum_repository.py
```

but If I create the directory structure in my working directory as: 
`ansible/modules/packaging/os/` and keep edited file `yum_repository.py` there, it should refer this edited file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ansible will look for modules in `./library` subdirectory of the playbook dir.

You can also use [`library` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#library) in the Ansible configuration file to specify a common directory for your modules.